# Why doesn't live() work on mobile safari?

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, jquery

I have the following test, I've been slamming my head against the wall trying to make it to work on mobile safari, it works on Android aswell as all the major web browsers - but doesn't run on mobile safari on iPhone 4, iOS 5.0.1, Any help would be appreciated.

All the JS is there.

Edit: what's not working is the close 'X' button.

[test case](http://liveglobalcams.com/test/test.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is a bug in jQuery 1.5! `live()` has some problems with mobile Safari!](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/5677)

Solutions:

- Update to current jQuery
- Add CSS `cursor: pointer` to the .close element
- Use click() instead of live and place this event handler inside doc.ready()

Other problems: The `div#install-notice` is not inside the body tag! Fix your HTML. [And validate it](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://liveglobalcams.com/test/test.php&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Comment: ahh yes, I forgot to mention -- this is a sandbox'd test, on the original site the document is declared as html 5 with <!DOCTYPE html> and is html5 valid.

Comment: No prob, but invalid HTML code is invalid HTML code. Fix your sandbox code.

Comment: There are still HTML markup errors on the page, check the Validator link in my comment! Add an `<title>` tag and add `type="text/javascript"` to the `<script>`.